# I'm having an issue with git ssh-key authentication to work

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I'm using a shared hosting ISP to host a simple website.
When I want to clone my code from github it keeps asking me for username and password and then tells me please use `token authentication`.
So I genereted key and added into `.ssh/id_d_ed25519.pub` and created config (following all the steps on github docs page). And I added the key to the ssh key section on github.

But on my ISP it keeps asking for login and password? And keeps telling me to use token authentication while I already configured it (and spend some hours on trying to figure out what is going on here). Why does it keep asking and not uses the ssh key?

Comment: Git*Hub* will require a token (instead of a password) when using `https://` URLs with HTTPS authentication. It will use ssh's authentication when using `ssh://` URLs with SSH authentication. (Note that neither kind of authentication is actually done *by* Git; Git shoves the job off onto other programs.)

Comment: Thanks snakecharmerb and torek,
I cleaned up everything and started all over again. Now it works. Not sure what was the problem/resolution.